# Relationship between government expenditure and exchange rate?

Tags: currency, foreign-exchange

I've read an increase in government expenditure can lead to increase the chances of currency crisis but shouldn't it lead to the opposite?

Fiscal deficit ----> Govt will undertake borrowings ---> crowding out -----> interest rates will rise ----> capital inflows -----> rise in forex/international reserves

what is wrong with my reasoning/logic?

Answer (score 1):

The **relationship between government expenditure and exchange rate** is an important one. The key question in current policy and academic debates is What are the effects of fiscal policy on aggregate economic activity in a globalized world?

The central challenge in this debate is how to identify fiscal shocks in the data. [Auerbach and Gorodnichenko (2015)](https://www.nber.org/papers/w21100) address this challenge by using daily data on US government spending. Exploiting this high-frequency data, they find that **unexpected government spending instantly affects exchange rates and the dollar appreciate**, which if I understand correctly supports your intuition.

The direction of the response of the exchange rate is consistent with basic macroeconomic theory; in an economy with a flexible exchange rate, government spending shocks should lead to appreciation of the domestic currency.